# Cross-compiling OpenCV with MinGW using CMake(in Linux for Windows)

Tags: opencv, cmake, mingw, cross-compiling

I'm trying to compile OpenCV library with MinGW in Linux for Windows using cmake-gui. I use toolchain file for cross-compilation Toolchain-mingw.cmake

```
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++)
SET(CMAKE_RC_COMPILER x86_64-w64-mingw32-windres)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH  /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32  )
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

When I try to configure, there are a lot of errors and I have no idea how to solve it

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:172    (configure_file):
configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:61 (project)


The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.0
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:167 (configure_file):
configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:61 (project)


The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.0
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:171 (configure_file):
configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:61 (project)


CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineRCCompiler.cmake:65 (configure_file):
configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/Platform/Windows-GNU.cmake:64 (enable_language)
/usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/Platform/Windows-GNU-CXX.cmake:1 (include)
/usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeCXXInformation.cmake:56 (include)
CMakeLists.txt:61 (project)


Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++
Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerABI.cmake:31 (try_compile):
Cannot copy output executable

'/media/data/distr/opencv-2.4.6.1/release4/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/cmTryCompileExec3943396232.exe'

to destination specified by COPY_FILE:

'/media/data/distr/opencv-2.4.6.1/release4/CMakeFiles/2.8.10.2/CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_CXX.bin'

Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:68 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ABI)
CMakeLists.txt:61 (project)


Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:71 (configure_file):
configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:61 (project)


Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerABI.cmake:31 (try_compile):
Cannot copy output executable

'/media/data/distr/opencv-2.4.6.1/release4/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/cmTryCompileExec2142254710.exe'

to destination specified by COPY_FILE:

'/media/data/distr/opencv-2.4.6.1/release4/CMakeFiles/2.8.10.2/CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_C.bin'

Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:75 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ABI)
CMakeLists.txt:61 (project)


Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:78 (configure_file):
configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:61 (project)


Detected version of GNU GCC: 48 (408)
CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVVersion.cmake:19 (configure_file):
configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:229 (include)


Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR
Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSTACKREALIGN
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSTACKREALIGN - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_MSTACKREALIGN
Performing Test HAVE_C_MSTACKREALIGN - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_W
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_W - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_W
Performing Test HAVE_C_W - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WALL
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WALL - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WALL
Performing Test HAVE_C_WALL - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE
Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_ADDRESS
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_ADDRESS - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_ADDRESS
Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_ADDRESS - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT
Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WFORMAT
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WFORMAT - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WFORMAT
Performing Test HAVE_C_WFORMAT - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY
Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS
Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES - Failed
Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES
Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES - Failed
Performing Test HAVE_C_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES
Performing Test HAVE_C_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNDEF
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNDEF - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNDEF
Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNDEF - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WINIT_SELF
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WINIT_SELF - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WINIT_SELF
Performing Test HAVE_C_WINIT_SELF - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WPOINTER_ARITH
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WPOINTER_ARITH - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WPOINTER_ARITH
Performing Test HAVE_C_WPOINTER_ARITH - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSHADOW
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSHADOW - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WSHADOW
Performing Test HAVE_C_WSHADOW - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSIGN_PROMO
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSIGN_PROMO - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WSIGN_PROMO
Performing Test HAVE_C_WSIGN_PROMO - Failed
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_NARROWING
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_NARROWING - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_NARROWING
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_NARROWING - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Failed
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS - Failed
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS - Failed
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION
Performing Test HAVE_C_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_LONG_LONG
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_LONG_LONG - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_LONG_LONG
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_LONG_LONG - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER
Performing Test HAVE_C_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE
Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE2
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE2 - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE2
Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE2 - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS
Performing Test HAVE_C_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS - Success
Looking for fseeko
Looking for fseeko - found
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CheckIncludeFile.cmake:40 (configure_file):
configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
3rdparty/zlib/CMakeLists.txt:24 (check_include_file)


Looking for unistd.h
Looking for unistd.h - found
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CheckIncludeFile.cmake:40 (configure_file):
configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CheckTypeSize.cmake:168 (check_include_file)
3rdparty/zlib/CMakeLists.txt:34 (check_type_size)


Looking for sys/types.h
Looking for sys/types.h - found
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CheckIncludeFile.cmake:40 (configure_file):
configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CheckTypeSize.cmake:169 (check_include_file)
3rdparty/zlib/CMakeLists.txt:34 (check_type_size)


Looking for stdint.h
Looking for stdint.h - found
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CheckIncludeFile.cmake:40 (configure_file):
configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CheckTypeSize.cmake:170 (check_include_file)
3rdparty/zlib/CMakeLists.txt:34 (check_type_size)


Looking for stddef.h
Looking for stddef.h - found
Check size of off64_t
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CheckTypeSize.cmake:91 (configure_file):
configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CheckTypeSize.cmake:177 (__check_type_size_impl)
3rdparty/zlib/CMakeLists.txt:34 (check_type_size)


CMake Error at 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeLists.txt:39 (configure_file):
configure_file Problem configuring file


Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_ATTRIBUTES
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_ATTRIBUTES - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_STRICT_PROTOTYPES
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_STRICT_PROTOTYPES - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_PROTOTYPES
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_PROTOTYPES - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CheckIncludeFile.cmake:40 (configure_file):
configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeLists.txt:10 (check_include_file)


Looking for assert.h
Looking for assert.h - found
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CheckIncludeFile.cmake:40 (configure_file):
configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeLists.txt:11 (check_include_file)


Looking for fcntl.h
Looking for fcntl.h - found
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CheckIncludeFile.cmake:40 (configure_file):
configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeLists.txt:12 (check_include_file)


Looking for io.h
Looking for io.h - found
Looking for jbg_newlen
Looking for jbg_newlen - not found
Looking for mmap
Looking for mmap - not found
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CheckIncludeFile.cmake:40 (configure_file):
configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeLists.txt:15 (check_include_file)


Looking for search.h
Looking for search.h - found
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CheckIncludeFile.cmake:40 (configure_file):
configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeLists.txt:16 (check_include_file)


Looking for string.h
Looking for string.h - found
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CheckIncludeFile.cmake:40 (configure_file):
configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeLists.txt:18 (check_include_file)


Looking for unistd.h
Looking for unistd.h - found
CMake Error at 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeLists.txt:24 (configure_file):
configure_file Problem configuring file


Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_BUT_SET_VARIABLE
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_BUT_SET_VARIABLE - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNDEF
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNDEF - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_CAST_ALIGN
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_CAST_ALIGN - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SHADOW
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SHADOW - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MAYBE_UNINITIALIZED
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MAYBE_UNINITIALIZED - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_POINTER_TO_INT_CAST
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_POINTER_TO_INT_CAST - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_INT_TO_POINTER_CAST
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_INT_TO_POINTER_CAST - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_PARAMETER
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_PARAMETER - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_PARAMETER
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_PARAMETER - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_IMPLICIT_FUNCTION_DECLARATION
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_IMPLICIT_FUNCTION_DECLARATION - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNINITIALIZED
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNINITIALIZED - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_BUT_SET_PARAMETER
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_BUT_SET_PARAMETER - Success
CMake Error at 3rdparty/openexr/CMakeLists.txt:14 (configure_file):
configure_file Problem configuring file


CMake Error at 3rdparty/openexr/CMakeLists.txt:16 (configure_file):
configure_file Problem configuring file


Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHADOW
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHADOW - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNDEF
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNDEF - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNINITIALIZED
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNINITIALIZED - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SWITCH
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SWITCH - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_PARENTHESES
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_PARENTHESES - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ARRAY_BOUNDS
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ARRAY_BOUNDS - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_EXTRA
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_EXTRA - Success
CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVFindLibsGUI.cmake:8 (TRY_COMPILE):
Failed to open

/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt

Нет такого файла или каталога
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:397 (include)


CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVFindLibsVideo.cmake:7 (TRY_COMPILE):
Failed to open

/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt

Нет такого файла или каталога
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:398 (include)


CUDA compilation is disabled (due to only Visual Studio compiler supported on your platform).
Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2 (found suitable version "2.7.4", minimum required is "2.0") 
Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing:  PYTHON_LIBRARIES PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS) (Required is exact version "2.7.4")
Could NOT find JNI (missing:  JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH) 
Could NOT find OPENCL (missing:  OPENCL_LIBRARY OPENCL_INCLUDE_DIR) 
CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVExtraTargets.cmake:4 (CONFIGURE_FILE):
configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:446 (include)


Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED_DECLARATIONS
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED_DECLARATIONS - Success
CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVGenHeaders.cmake:12 (configure_file):
configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:493 (include)


CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVGenHeaders.cmake:35 (configure_file):
configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:493 (include)


CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVGenPkgconfig.cmake:71 (configure_file):
configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:496 (include)


CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVGenConfig.cmake:122 (configure_file):
configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:502 (include)


CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVGenConfig.cmake:124 (configure_file):
configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:502 (include)


CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVGenConfig.cmake:145 (configure_file):
configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:502 (include)


CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVGenConfig.cmake:146 (configure_file):
configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:502 (include)


CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVGenConfig.cmake:178 (configure_file):
configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:502 (include)


CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVGenConfig.cmake:179 (configure_file):
configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:502 (include)



General configuration for OpenCV 2.4.6.1 =====================================
Version control:               unknown

Platform:
Host:                        Linux 3.8.7-1-ARCH x86_64
Target:                      Windows
CMake:                       2.8.10.2
CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
Configuration:               Release

C/C++:
Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++  (ver 4.8.0)
C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -mstackrealign -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -ffunction-sections -O2 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -mstackrealign -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -ffunction-sections -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG -ggdb3
C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -mstackrealign -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -ffunction-sections -O2 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -mstackrealign -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -ffunction-sections -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG -ggdb3
Linker flags (Release):      
Linker flags (Debug):        
Precompiled headers:         YES

OpenCV modules:
To be built:                 core imgproc flann highgui features2d calib3d ml video objdetect contrib photo legacy gpu nonfree stitching superres ts videostab
Disabled:                    world
Disabled by dependency:      -
Unavailable:                 androidcamera java ocl python

GUI: 
QT:                          NO
Win32 UI:                    NO
OpenGL support:              NO

Media I/O: 
ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.7)
JPEG:                        build (ver 62)
PNG:                         build (ver 1.5.12)
TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.2)
JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)

Video I/O:
Video for Windows:           NO
DC1394 1.x:                  NO
DC1394 2.x:                  NO
FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
codec:                     YES (ver 53.61.100)
format:                    YES (ver 53.32.100)
util:                      YES (ver 51.35.100)
swscale:                   YES (ver 2.1.100)
gentoo-style:              YES
OpenNI:                      NO
OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
PvAPI:                       NO
GigEVisionSDK:               NO
DirectShow:                  YES
Media Foundation:            NO
XIMEA:                       NO

Other third-party libraries:
Use IPP:                     NO
Use Eigen:                   NO
Use TBB:                     NO
Use OpenMP:                  NO
Use GCD                      NO
Use Concurrency              NO
Use C=:                      NO
Use Cuda:                    NO
Use OpenCL:                  NO

Python:
Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2 (ver 2.7.4)

Java:
ant:                         NO
JNI:                         NO
Java tests:                  NO

Documentation:
Build Documentation:         NO
Sphinx:                      NO
PdfLaTeX compiler:           /usr/bin/pdflatex

Tests and samples:
Tests:                       YES
Performance tests:           YES
C/C++ Examples:              NO

Install path:                  /media/data/distr/opencv-2.4.6.1/release4/install

cvconfig.h is in:              /media/data/distr/opencv-2.4.6.1/release4
-----------------------------------------------------------------

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, after using an old version of CMAKE 2.8.8 everything was working again without any error.

You can check the following link for more details:
https://sourceforge.net/p/podofo/mailman/podofo-users/thread/BLU157-ds114B45D1CA3DC934BF77C3E1CB0@phx.gbl/

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

## static cross-compiling `opencv 4.5.3` under linux `fedora 33` using `cmake 3.17.4` with `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc`

the following bash script downloads opencv and compiles statically wor windows using mingw

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e  # stop script if anything does not execute properly

SRCFOLDER=src
BINFOLDER=build_mingw64_static

wget https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/4.5.3.zip

unzip 4.5.3.zip -d tmp
mkdir ${SRCFOLDER}
mv tmp/opencv-4.5.3/* ${SRCFOLDER}

rm -rf "./tmp"


cmake -S ${SRCFOLDER} -B ${BINFOLDER} \
    -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Windows \
    -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DWITH_OPENEXR=OFF -DWITH_FFMPEG=OFF \
    2>&1 | tee log_cmake.txt
cd ${BINFOLDER}
make 2>&1 | tee ../log_make.txt
make install 2>&1 | tee ../log_make-install.txt

echo "opencv compiled successfully :)"
```