# cmake error using the mingw-w64-x86_64 gcc toolchain under Windows 7 : "this program has been built without plugin support"

Tags: gcc, windows-7, mingw-w64, msys2, nanomsg

I have a setup with Windows 7, [MSYS2](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS2), [Mingw-w64-x86_64 gcc toolchain](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/4.8.2/threads-posix/seh/x86_64-4.8.2-release-posix-seh-rt_v3-rev3.7z/download), [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/resources/software.html), and I am trying to build the [nanomsg library](https://github.com/nanomsg/nanomsg).

Here is what I obtain :

> $ cmake --debug-trycompile
>   -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../toolchain_i686-pc-mingw32.cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32 -G "MinGW Makefiles"  ../nanomsg

```
debug trycompile on
```

> -- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
>   -- Check for working C compiler: C:/mingw64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe
>   -- Check for working C compiler: C:/mingw64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe -- broken CMake Error at
>   C:/cmake-win32-x86/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61
>   (message):   The C compiler
>   "C:/mingw64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe" is not able to   compile a
>   simple test program.
>
> It fails with the following output:
>
> Change Dir:
>   C:/msys64/home/Laurent/Dev/nanomsg-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command:C:/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe
>   "cmTryCompileExec910276652/fast"
>
> C:/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f
>   CMakeFiles\cmTryCompileExec910276652.dir\build.make
>   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec910276652.dir/build
>
> mingw32-make.exe[1](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS2): Entering directory
>   'C:/msys64/home/Laurent/Dev/nanomsg-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>
> C:\cmake-win32-x86\bin\cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report
>   C:\msys64\home\Laurent\Dev\nanomsg-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CMakeFiles
>   1
>
> Building C object
>   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec910276652.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
>
> C:\mingw64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe -o
>   CMakeFiles\cmTryCompileExec910276652.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj -c
>   C:\msys64\home\Laurent\Dev\nanomsg-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c
>
> Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec910276652.exe
>
> C:\cmake-win32-x86\bin\cmake.exe -E cmake_link_script
>   CMakeFiles\cmTryCompileExec910276652.dir\link.txt --verbose=1
>
> C:\cmake-win32-x86\bin\cmake.exe -E remove -f
>   CMakeFiles\cmTryCompileExec910276652.dir/objects.a
>
> x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-ar cr
>   CMakeFiles\cmTryCompileExec910276652.dir/objects.a
>   @CMakeFiles\cmTryCompileExec910276652.dir\objects1.rsp
>
> sorry - this program has been built without plugin support
>
> CMakeFiles\cmTryCompileExec910276652.dir\build.make:91: recipe for
>   target   'cmTryCompileExec910276652.exe' failed
>
> mingw32-make.exe[1](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS2): *** [cmTryCompileExec910276652.exe] Error 1
>
> mingw32-make.exe[1](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS2): Leaving directory
>   'C:/msys64/home/Laurent/Dev/nanomsg-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>
> Makefile:116: recipe for target 'cmTryCompileExec910276652/fast'
>   failed
>
> mingw32-make.exe: *** [cmTryCompileExec910276652/fast] Error 2
>
> CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project. Call
>   Stack (most recent call first):   CMakeLists.txt:29 (project)

Here is my toolchain file:

```
$ cat ../toolchain_i686-pc-mingw32.cmake
# http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling#The_toolchain_file
# http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=8959
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754316/cross-compiling-opencv-with-mingw-using-cmakein-linux-for-windows

# this one is important
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)
#this one not so much
#SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)

# specify the cross compiler
SET(PREFIX x86_64-w64-mingw32)
SET(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM mingw32-make)
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   ${PREFIX}-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${PREFIX}-g++)
SET(CMAKE_AR ${PREFIX}-gcc-ar)
SET(CMAKE_NM ${PREFIX}-gcc-nm)
SET(CMAKE_RC_COMPILER  windres)

# specify the cross linker
SET(CMAKE_RANLIB ${PREFIX}-gcc-ranlib)

# where is the target environment
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /opt/mingw64 /usr/${PREFIX})

# search for programs in the build host directories
#SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
# for libraries and headers in the target directories
#SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
#SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

It looks like it fails to build on an auto test because the toolchain misses *plugin support*.

Here is my gcc version and options:

```
$ /opt/mingw64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\mingw64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.2/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../../../src/gcc-4.8.2/configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/mingw64 --with-sysroot=/c/mingw482/x86_64-482-posix-seh-rt_v3-rev3/mingw64 --with-gxx-include-dir=/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++ --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-multilib --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,lto --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-threads=posix --enable-libgomp --enable-libatomic --enable-lto --enable-graphite --enable-checking=release --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --disable-isl-version-check --disable-cloog-version-check --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-bootstrap --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-arch=nocona --with-tune=core2 --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/c/mingw482/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpfr=/c/mingw482/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpc=/c/mingw482/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-isl=/c/mingw482/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-cloog=/c/mingw482/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --enable-cloog-backend=isl --with-pkgversion='x86_64-posix-seh-rev3, Built by MinGW-W64 project' --with-bugurl=http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64 CFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -I/c/mingw482/x86_64-482-posix-seh-rt_v3-rev3/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/mingw482/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw482/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CXXFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -I/c/mingw482/x86_64-482-posix-seh-rt_v3-rev3/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/mingw482/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw482/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CPPFLAGS= LDFLAGS='-pipe -L/c/mingw482/x86_64-482-posix-seh-rt_v3-rev3/mingw64/opt/lib -L/c/mingw482/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/lib -L/c/mingw482/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/lib '
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev3, Built by MinGW-W64 project)
```

1. Is it related to the "--enable-plugin" option (missing in my gcc) ?
2. Is there somewhere a toolchain build available with this option set ? I looked for it in MSYS2, Mingw-w64, rubenvb repositories, but it is not there. Or shall I build it myself ?
3. Possibly nanomsg does not need it ? Does the autotest requires it because nanomsg needs it ? Or can I prevent this autotest from being run ? Or can I set something to avoid the need of the "--enable-plugins" option ?

Comment: Under the QT Mingw32 environment, it works.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are using the MSYS2 shell here, and not MSYS2 itself. If you were using an up to date MSYS2 then you'd be using the following mingw-w64 x86_64 GCC:

```
$ pacman -Ss mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc 4.9.1-6

$ PATH=/mingw64/bin:$PATH gcc -v
Configured with: ... --enable-lto ...
```

--enable-lto implies --enable-plugins which is the default now and so doesn't appear in the list.

To build nanomsg with MSYS2, install https://master-dl.sourceforge.net/project/msys2/Base/x86_64/msys2-x86_64-20141003.exe, untick "Run MSYS2 shell now" (you want a mingw-w64 shell instead). Run the mingw-w64 shell (Start->MSYS2 64Bit->MinGW-w64 Win64 Shell). From within that shell:

```
$ pacman -S git make mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc
$ git clone https://github.com/nanomsg/nanomsg.git
$ mkdir nanomsg-build
$ cd nanomsg-build
$ cmake --debug-trycompile -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32 -G "MSYS Makefiles" ../nanomsg
$ make install
```

But if you are a developer, we'd appreciate the [contribution](http://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/wiki/Contributing%20to%20MSYS2/) of a PKGBUILD for nanomsg